# How to update status in database if status is empty without submitting a form in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

How to update a status from database if status is empty in using php? I have this condition in php. I have this if condition that decides if `$getstatus` is empty it will update from database to `Avail`. I tried refreshing the page after querying the database. But it will not update in database. Is there anyway to update this without using form submit in php?

```
<?php
session_start();
include "includes/connection.php";

// Display all parking slots
$sql = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM parkingslot where parkingslotid = 1');
$sql->execute(); // execute query
$result = $sql->get_result(); // fetch result

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $getstatus = $row["status"];
    echo $getstatus;
  }
}

if (empty($getstatus)) {
  $sql = $connection->prepare("UPDATE parkingslot SET status = 'Avail' where parkingslotid = 1 ");
}

?>
```

Codes in connection for connecting to database

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password);

// check connection
if(!$connection)
{
  die("No connection found." . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
  // select a database
  $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection,'smartparkingsystem');

  if(!$select_db)
  {
    $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE sample';

    // create database if no db found
    if(mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) {
      echo "Database Created";
    }
    else {
      echo "Database not found" . mysqli_connect_error() . '\n';
    }
  }
  else {
      // Database already existed
      // do nothing...
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: I've updated my select query, I want to update the status in parkinglotid =1 only

Comment: Do a `var_dump($getstatus)` and check what that value is.

Comment: Why a while loop if you are only ever going to get 1 or 0 rows in the resultset ???

Comment: You don't seem to execute your second query, you only prepare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If I understand your goal of:** For row(s) where`parkingslotid`=`1` - Update `status` to 'Avail' but only if `status` is not currently set, this might help:

```
<?php

session_start();
include "includes/connection.php";

$connection->prepare("UPDATE `parkingslot` SET `status`=? WHERE `parkingslotid`=? AND (`status` IS NULL OR `status`=?)");

$connection->bind_param("sis", $status, $parkingslotid, $empty_str);

$status = 'Avail';
$parkingslotid = 1;
$empty_str = '';

$connection->execute(); 

echo $connection->affected_rows.' rows affected';

$connection->close();

?>
```

This saves a bit of processing by not checking with PHP first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
"UPDATE parkingslot SET status = 'Avail' where status IS NULL OR status = '' "
```

Comment: This code updates all the status in my database but what I want to update is the `parkinglot id = 1` only.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

@lumonald gave the right anwser in the comment. You're not executing your second SQL statement.